# Love Live: Yon, nana, and not shi, shichi? (Counting from 1 to 9)

Tags: japanese-language, love-live

In the anime *Love Live*, when the nine girls count from one to nine in Japanese, they say:

> Ichi ni san **yon** go roku **nana** hachi kyuu

And not:

> Ichi ni san **shi** go roku **shichi** hachi kyuu

---

What is the reason?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Four (四) being Yon not being Shi, this is because in Japanese Death is written as 死 and pronounced as Shi

> There are six unlucky numbers in Japanese. Traditionally, 4 is unlucky because it is sometimes pronounced shi, which is the word for death. Sometimes levels or rooms with 4 don't exist in hospitals or hotels. Particularly in the maternity section of a hospital, the room number 43 is avoided because it can literally mean "stillbirth". (死産 - shizan: 死 - death/to die and 産 - childbirth/produce).

[Japanese superstitions > Linguistic superstition > Numbers > Unlucky Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_superstitions#Unlucky_Numbers)

---

Seven (七) being Nana and not Shichi is sometimes in the same boat because of the same superstition above, however

> 7, when pronounced with "shichi", sounds similar to the number four (四 shi). It is considered a good number since 7 symbolizes "Togetherness".

[Japanese superstitions > Linguistic superstition > Numbers > Lucky Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_superstitions#Lucky_Numbers)

---

Nine (九) in Japanese is [Kyuu](https://l-lingo.com/free-lessons/en/learn-japanese/numbers-1-10.html) so i believe you are hearing it wrong.

However it should be noted that 9 can be pronounced as Ku however in this instance it is like Shi as

> Number 9 is sometimes pronounced ku — with the same pronunciation as agony or torture. Combs (kushi) are rarely given as presents as the name is pronounced the same as 9 4.

[Japanese superstitions > Linguistic superstition > Numbers > Unlucky Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_superstitions#Unlucky_Numbers)

and i have never been taught to use Ku<sup>1</sup>

---

<sub>1: only discovered Ku when i looked up Wikipedia for 7, in all my classes it has always been Kyuu</sub>

Comment: Uh... I've edited my question - 9 is generally **kyuu** ("ku" is only in rare exceptions) and they were saying it right.